# Fonts and icons on Windows 11 VirtualBox VM are too small

Tags: windows, virtualbox

This problem happens on "WinDev2204Eval.VirtualBox". I fixed this problem and it may help others too.

[WinDev2204Eval.VirtualBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CiPEF.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the VM, go to to **Settings --> Accessibility --> Text area**
Then you can adjust the size

[image: WinDev2204Eval.VirtualBox]

Comment: Settings->Display->Scale Factor (150%) fixed for me.